# Accessing min and max constant from a yup schema

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I'm trying to write a react native application using Formik + Yup for schema validation and I'm having some trouble trying to extract the constants passed in max validation.

Let's imagine the following schema:

```
const message = string()
  .max(30)
  .default(1)
```

In my React Native component, let's say a custom `TextInput`, I wanted to get the constants `30` so that I can pass it to the `maxLength` prop:

```
<TextInput maxLength={max} {...otherProps} />
```

(*of course the schema is simplified*)

Does anybody know if it's feasible? How I can dig into a yup schema to access that constant and pass it to my `TextInput`?

Comment: You want to deliver 30 when the letter "TextInput" is 30?

Comment: I want my TextInput to be limited to 30, I want to extract the 30 constant from the Yup schema :) so that I define it in only one place

Answer (score 3):

Call schema.describe(). This will return a description of the schema including a "tests" array. One of the items in the test array will be have a name "max", and also a "params" object containing a "max" value.

```
const description = schema.describe();
const maxTest = description.tests.find(t => t.name === 'max');
const maxValue = maxTest && maxTest.params ? maxTest.params.max : undefined;
```

You should be able to get access to most of the validations in the same way, however there's not currently a way to learn whether transformations like 'lowercase' and 'strip' are applied.

You will of course have to expose the schema for each field to do the above. Alternatively you can call describe() on the parent object schema and interrogate interrogate the "fields" property, then do something similar to the above.

Comment: I tried that, but the "tests" array is empty (which doesn't seem about right, as I do have rules applied to my schema / that particular field that I'm testing with). Is this a documented way of achieving this or is this using / abusing private methods?

Comment: This is useful if you don't have control over Yup schema, but you get it from somewhere. Otherwise it could be better (safer and more readable) to use @Anuja response and use a constant to create both the schema and the TextInput maxLength.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `function` to `validationSchema` prop, so basically your `yup` schema would be,

```
const validationSchema = value => Yup.object().shape({
   name : Yup.string().max(values.max).default(1)
  });
```

In `<Formik/>` component level render method,

```
const { max } = this.state;

<Formik
 validationSchema={()=> validationSchema({max}) 
 ...>
  <TextInput maxLength={max} {...otherProps} />
</Formik>
```

Comment: Yes, but it won't pass the `max(30)` to the `maxLength` of my textinput. I don't want to be in error while I'm crossing 30 chars, I just want to not be able to cross 30 chars

Comment: you could do that, i passed 30 as an example, do you need partly validations per component?

Comment: since you have access to the `max` value at `<Formik/>` level if you do it in the way i said,  you can pass it down like. 

`const { max } = this.state;`
    `return <Formik validationSchema={()=> validationSchema({max}) />`
                 `<TextInput maxLength={max} {...otherProps}/>`
              `</Formik>`

like so.